# Jquery wrapping elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML output that I need to wrap with a new div (.container). Sometimes the span.diary-film-name will be followed by some links a.film-tickets-link. If the links are there I want them wrapped in the .container div too.

Let me clarify, I can't change the HTML Output, hence this approach.

I can wrap the span.diary-film-name by using the line below but I'm not sure about wrapping the following links if present?

```
$( ".diary-film-name" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" );
```

This is what I have:

```
<span class="diary-film-name">
    <a href="#">Toy Story 1</a>
</span>
<a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">5.20pm</a>
<a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">7.40pm</a>

<span class="diary-film-name">
    <a href="#">Toy Story 2</a>
</span>
```

This is what I want to display with the new  .container div:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="diary-film-name">
        <a href="#">Toy Story 1</a>
    </span>
    <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">5.20pm</a>
    <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">7.40pm</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span class="diary-film-name">
        <a href="#">Toy Story 2</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm doing this so I can delete the container if there are no .film-ticket-links within , i.e.

```
$('.container').not(':has(.film-tickets-link)').remove();
```

**Edit:** the only I can do this is by adding a <*br*> before and after the span. This is the only change I can make in the original output:

```
$('.my-page br').each(function(){
 $(this).nextUntil('.my-page br').wrapAll(document.createElement('div'));
});
```

I've managed to resolve this...

```
$(".diary-film-name").each(function(){
$(this).nextUntil(".diary-film-name").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="container">  </div>')
})
```

Comment: Can't you already wrap? `<div class="filmContainer"><span class="diary-film-name">
    <a href="#">Toy Story 1</a>
</span>
<a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">5.20pm</a>
<a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">7.40pm</a></div>` then you can hide all and use `$("div.filmContainer").has(".film-tickets-link").show()`

Comment: No because the .film-tickets-link are not contained. I can't render a container div from the source hence I need to do it with JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Edited with each()

As you said that the HTML can't be edited, i'll add a pure jquery solution:
First, do it as you where doing, that will create this structure:

```
  <div class="container">
     <span class="diary-film-name">
         <a href="#">Toy Story 1</a>
     </span>
  </div>
  <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">5.20pm</a>
  <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">7.40pm</a>
```

So, we wrap the container, then we select all elements in the same level that has the .film-tickets-link class, then we append them to the end of container:

```
 var containers = $( ".diary-film-name" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" ).parent();
 containers.each(function(index, element){

  const links = $(this).nextUntil('.container');
  links.appendTo(element);

})
```

Problem here is the container class, it has to be unique (If not, it will not work, you could use id or some data field that is populated from the api with unique identifier)
I did not "compile" it, so maybe there are some syntax error, but the logic is okay.

**OLD**

If you use the span container

```
.diary-film-name
```

If links exists and you wrap it by it, the links below will be outside of the container, my advice, change the structure of the HTML, add an span in top of .diary-film-name, that will wrap both fil name and fil links

```
<div class="container">
 <span class="content-container">
    <span class="diary-film-name">
        <a href="#">Toy Story 1</a>
    </span>
    <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">5.20pm</a>
    <a class="film-tickets-link" href="#">7.40pm</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

Then instead of

```
$( ".diary-film-name" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" );
```

Do:

```
$( ".content-container" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" );
```

Comment: I'm having issues changing the HTML due to the system we are using hence this approach... I need to do some kind of check i.e. start new div wrap before span, check if it has links below up until the next span then close the div after those kinks.

Comment: @ultrarun you could do as you are doing and then iterate trought the links below and if they exist move them inside the container, i'll write the code in a few minutes check it.

Comment: Thanks but it closes the container before the links https://jsfiddle.net/kdrysdale/6yvgutkL/1/

Comment: @ultrarun fixed it, check it now :)

Comment: That's awesome thanks, but if I add more spans it appends all of the links to the spans, see what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/kdrysdale/6yvgutkL/4/ Is there a way to restrict appending to just the links directly below each span to the new container

Comment: Doesn't seem to be closing the div?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this...

```
$(".diary-film-name").each(function(){
$(this).nextUntil(".diary-film-name").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="container">  </div>')
})
```

Comment: I upated with new code that now is working, if you want to check it, its a little clearer than yours.

Answer (score -4):

Regard `container`: you can have more containers but you can't nest them according to bootstrap documentation. So, your html structure is ok.

Moreover, your source code is suitable to achieve the results you wan but, if you want to have just one `container` and you can't change the html structure rendering from back, you can do it directly through Jquery.